# C# Linq Pivot data with variable columns

Tags: c#, linq

In the code below, i'm returning data that will have a variable number of columns.
So it could return columns 'a,b,c,d,e' or it could return columns 'a,b,c,g,m,n' - the first three columns are set, but then there could be any number of additional columns.  I then need to return the data as an anonymous type list.  In the code below, i'm showing how i get the data, pivot it, and add the columns into `ArrayList objDataColumn` , and then create a datatable, which does get me close, but i'm not able to figure out how to return the data as a list.

Instead of having it return a list of `datatable` rows, i'd like to have it return a generic list of anonymous type like the following (in this case 'Attribute' is the only dynamic column):

```
{ EntitlementId = 477653184, FileSetTypeID = 146, FileTypeCode = "test", SourceSystemKey = "userkey", Entitlement = "Chg Mgrs - AppDev Sour GUI", Attribute = "Change Manager" }

  ////Applying linq for geting pivot output
            var d = (from f in result
                     group f by new { f.EntitlementId, f.FileSetTypeID, f.FileTypeCode, f.SourceSystemKey, f.Entitlement }
                         into myGroup
                         where myGroup.Count() > 0
                         select new
                         {
                             myGroup.Key.EntitlementId,
                             myGroup.Key.FileSetTypeID,
                             myGroup.Key.FileTypeCode,
                             myGroup.Key.SourceSystemKey,
                             myGroup.Key.Entitlement,
                             ColumnName = myGroup.GroupBy(f => f.ColumnName).Select(m => new { Col = m.Key, Value = m.Max(c => c.Value) })
                         }).ToList();

            //PART 2 - Distinct ColumnName 
            var cols = (
                         from a in result
                         select new { ColumnName = a.ColumnName }
                         ).Distinct().ToList();

            //PART 3 - Creating array for adding dynamic columns
            ArrayList objDataColumn = new ArrayList();

            //Fixed columns
            objDataColumn.Add("FileTypeCode");
            objDataColumn.Add("SourceSystemKey");
            objDataColumn.Add("Entitlement");

            //Add Subject Name as column in Datatable
            for (int i = 0; i < cols.Count; i++)
            {
                objDataColumn.Add(cols[i].ColumnName);
            }


            //Add dynamic columns name to datatable dt

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < objDataColumn.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(objDataColumn[i].ToString());
            }

            //PART 4 - Add data into datatable with respect to dynamic columns and dynamic data
            for (int i = 0; i < d.Count; i++)
            {
                List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
                tempList.Add(result[i].FileTypeCode.ToString());
                tempList.Add(result[i].SourceSystemKey.ToString());
                tempList.Add(result[i].Entitlement.ToString());

                var res = d[i].ColumnName.ToList();
                for (int j = 0; j < res.Count; j++)
                {
                    tempList.Add(res[j].Value.ToString());
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(tempList.ToArray<string>());
            }

            //END PIVOT 

            IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = dt.AsEnumerable();
```

Thanks in advance, let me know if any additional info is needed, hope this isnt too confusing.

Comment: Anonymous types are compiler feature, hence cannot be created dynamically at runtime.

Comment: I believe  to find a solution it would help if you describe a little more what your end objective is.
I say this because Your end objective is a somewhat unclear and it seems like there may be a simpler way to get to where you want to be.
Are you trying to generate classes dynamically? or maybe just a dynamic data structure ?
You have some good code here, but it may be overly involved for what you are trying to get to?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, My end goal is that i have to populate a devexpress mvc gridview with an IEnumerable object.  Using the datatable method in my code isnt necessary, just an attempt to get the data formatted correctly.  Since the properties will change depending on input parameters, that's the tricky part.

Comment: why don't use specialized library like NReco PivotData? It can easily [group data by variable columns](http://www.nrecosite.com/pivotdata/dynamic-data-aggregation-and-grouping.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve this using a dynamic list and the ExpandoObject class.
Here's the code, hope it helps someone else:

```
  List<dynamic> dynList = new List<dynamic>();
            for (int i = 0; i < d.Count; i++)
            {
                dynamic dynObj = new ExpandoObject();
                ((IDictionary<string, object>)dynObj).Add("FileTypeCode", result[i].FileTypeCode.ToString());
                ((IDictionary<string, object>)dynObj).Add("Fullname", result[i].Fullname.ToString());
                ((IDictionary<string, object>)dynObj).Add("Entitlement", result[i].Entitlement.ToString());

                var res = d[i].ColumnName.ToList();
                for (int j = 0; j < res.Count; j++)
                {
                    ((IDictionary<string, object>)dynObj).Add(res[j].Col.ToString(), res[j].Value.ToString());
                }

                dynList.Add(dynObj);
            }
            var dList = (from da in dynList select da).ToList();

            return dList;
```